# Comandos de ordem inversa/upper/ troque

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um trabalho (Python 3) e preciso de ajuda para concluir os códigos.

- Preciso saber como eu inverto a ordem, por exemplo 2345 de entrada e saída de 5432.
- Preciso saber também como eu deixo apenas uma letra maiúscula e o resto minúscula, como exemplo: stackoverflow (deixar apenas a letra o maiúscula)?
- E por fim preciso saber como eu troco `x` por `y` e vice-versa. Por exemplo: `y = 23x^2 - 2x + 1` (entrada) e `x = 23y^2 - 2y + 1` (saída).

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Olá MrX, este site é destinado a ajudar usuários à tirarem suas dúvidas específicas. Dificilmente aqui alguém te dará a resposta pronta, ainda mais se tratando de um trabalho como vc disse. Poste o código que já tentou até então e esclareça sua dúvida, poderia começar dizendo se o que está tentando fazer é em Javascript ou Phyton.

Comment: Na descrição você cita *Phyton*, contudo marca *JavaScript* como *tag*.

Comment: A tag não tinha phyton....

Comment: Outro problema também, inclusive já teve uma questão anteriormente abordando o caso, como um código iria saber qual "o" da palavra "stackoverflow" seria convertida em maiúscula? Seria preciso um dicionário.

Comment: A tag é **Python**, e não Phyton.

Comment: A primeira coisa que você precisa é aprender a digitar o nome da linguagem corretamente.

Comment: o exercico pede para todos os "a" virarem maiúsculo e até agora ninguém me ajuda

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Inverter número (em uma função):

```
def reverse_number(n):
  r = 0
  while n > 0:
    r *= 10
    r += n % 10
    n /= 10
  return r
```

Deixar uma letra maiúscula:

```
u"stackoverflow".title()
```

Substituir `x` por `y` e vice-versa:

```
"y = 23x^2 - 2x + 1".upper().replace("X", "y").replace("Y","x")
```

Todas as letras em minúsculas, exceto a letra a:

```
"NAISNDFOAISOASID".lower().replace("a","A")
```

Comment: Um exercício bem tosco que não consigo resolver
Faça um programa que dada uma palavra, transforme todas suas letras em letras minúsculas.
Exceto a letra 'a'.
É algo bem simples, não pode complicar e eu não estou conseguindo...

Comment: A de vice-versa não é so pra equaçao é pra geral, ou seja, troca de variaveis.... segue o exercicio: Faça um programa que dada a expressão algébrica de uma equação do segundo grau, troque x por y e
vice versa. 
A equação sempre estará disposta na forma: 
 y=ax2+bx+c

Comment: Evite fazer múltiplas perguntas em uma mesma, aconselho que realize outra pergunta, caso a dúvida seja de uma implementação diferente desta.

Comment: No caso da equação é só substituir a `string` fixa pela sua equação (que pode ser qualquer uma)

Comment: Caso essa pergunta tenha te ajudado, não esqueça de marcar como certa e votar positivamente :)

Comment: O forum disponibiliza 1 pergunta a cada 40 minutos e eu tenho 1 hora para resolver esses 3 exercícios. Poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Editei a resposta e resolvi essa outra exceção do 'a', as outras estão feitas.